# how to draw a directed graph using all outliers from BoxWhiskerChart[]

Tags: graphs-and-networks, charts

Given a matrix (15, 15), find and assign value `1` to all the `BoxWhiskerChart[]` outliers and then draw a directed graph of the outliers only.

```
backMult={0., 0.00229335, 0.104164, 0.00111408, 0.00321884, 0.0207657,       0.024855, 0.0226118, 0.00614017, 0.000366926, 0.00861721, 0.00276732,     0.0100621, 0.0140898, 0.00205675, 0.0229372, 0., 0.177012, 0.389297,     0.485754, 0.100644, 0.0180664, 0.0405537, 0.0292081, 0.00127345,     0.0295883, 0.00675072, 0.0213518, 0.0853784, 0.00855642, 0.136734,     0.0269428, 0., 0.0131134, 0.0334586, 0.24534, 0.0531405, 0.131401,     0.056403, 0.00378599, 0.0601253, 0.0161052, 0.0619286, 0.127442,     0.0214381, 0.00617562, 0.00155166, 0.0233257, 0., 0.00882376,     0.00729392, 0.00386352, 0.00493301, 0.0260629, 0.000306704,     0.00904818, 0.0019964, 0.00812619, 0.0138727, 0.00148075, 0.0085175,     0.00316032, 0.0282666, 0.00136567, 0., 0.010804, 0.0161482,     0.0126221, 0.012248, 0.000521799, 0.0130656, 0.00615699, 0.0189117,     0.0420866, 0.00382247, 0.00251853, 0.000723917, 0.00443665,     0.000330214, 0.0046494, 0., 0.00855759, 0.00214561, 0.0109788,     0.00056165, 0.011194, 0.00312936, 0.021479, 0.0133749, 0.00126997,     0.0617627, 0.0123207, 0.148779, 0.00612953, 0.0361287, 0.106632, 0.,     0.0492443, 0.0819006, 0.00304001, 0.0747691, 0.0112115, 0.0268386,     0.0850206, 0.0119646, 0.000500567, 0.000622086, 0.00141268,     0.000259116, 0.000875407, 0.00254647, 0.00161678, 0., 0.00279339,     0.000251721, 0.00471751, 0.000768647, 0.00333403, 0.00903986,     0.00056927, 0.013511, 0.00794974, 0.0404202, 0.0038107, 0.0190081,     0.0373082, 0.0338646, 0.015702, 0., 0.00710453, 0.0749049, 0.0338378,     0.0384485, 0.0732616, 0.00986711, 0.0693907, 0.013335, 0.105714,     0.00799703, 0.0584009, 0.214043, 0.174936, 0.0334414, 0.143252, 0.,     0.12566, 0.0477588, 0.105827, 0.117263, 0.0325825, 0.0126751,     0.0200846, 0.0414654, 0.00860318, 0.0255745, 0.0802224, 0.0576015,    0.0236192, 0.0757278, 0.00516437, 0., 0.011979, 0.0400479, 0.0719813,     0.0102082, 0.000158159, 0.000092188, 0.000334735, 0.0000477598,     0.000292762, 0.000244762, 0.00054631, 0.0000764493, 0.000293929,     0.0000138531, 0.000239881, 0., 0.00136438, 0.000313043, 0.0000781203,     0.000246596, 0.000142221, 0.000573169, 0.000073708, 0.000442703,     0.000405117, 0.00114298, 0.000141802, 0.000597492, 0.0000191262,     0.000447595, 0.000318337, 0., 0.000625299, 0.000129184, 0.00604589,     0.0023468, 0.0136537, 0.00115514, 0.00764016, 0.0165812, 0.0137514,     0.00491768, 0.0236434, 0.0059057, 0.0232222, 0.0115159, 0.00589417,     0., 0.00828583, 0.00311216, 0.000981488, 0.00508806, 0.00053171,     0.00339738, 0.00286083, 0.00994436, 0.00308703, 0.00776784, 0.001247,     0.00896249, 0.00112446, 0.00603177, 0.0188474, 0.};
```

This produces BWC with the outliers shown:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[
backMult, {{"FarOutliers", "\[FilledSmallCircle]", Red}, {"Outliers", 
"\FilledSmallCircle]"}}];
```

My specific question is how to identify the BWC outliers in a matrix and assign a value `1`, otherwise assign `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Properties & Relations section of the documentation for BoxWhiskerChart describes how near and far outliers are determined using the quartiles and interquartile range of your data. It appears that BoxWhiskerChart identifies near outliers as those that fall beyond the third quartile + 1.5*interquartile range and up to q3+3*interquartile range, and the far outliers as those that go beyond even that. So you can isolate them using `Select`:

```
{q1, median, q3} = Quartiles[backMult]
iqr = q3 - q1

near = Select[backMult, q3 + 1.5 iqr <= # < q3 + 3 iqr &]
far = Select[backMult, # >= q3 + 3 iqr &]
```

... or you could extract the corresponding points from BoxWhiskerChart.

Comment: This answer solves the most important part of my question. I can do the rest of the calculations to create the two directed graphs based on two sets of outliers. Thanks.